# Major PHP error in Drupal

Tags: drupal

Trying to interpret this error and why it is happening:

```
Call to undefined function fivestar_widget_form() in 
/home/readyby2/public_html/sites
/all/themes/readyby21/templates/page--resource.tpl.php on line 73
```

The directory is there, downloaded from the drupal main site, inside the modules directory.

Could there be some conflict?

Comment: You have an undefined function called `fivestar_widget_form()` on line 73 of `page--resource.tpl.php`

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense! fivestar_widget_form() absolutely exists!

Comment: Not according to php. :) Post more code to get more help

Comment: ahh that drupal, where everything exists but nothing works. Are you sure this function is included? i mean function_exists("fivestar_widget_form") works? Also check [here](http://drupal.org/node/1114726) for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the version of the module for Drupal 6, then `fivestar_widget_form()` is defined in the fivestar.module file; if you are getting that error, it means the module is not enabled, or it has not been loaded the moment the template file is being used. It could also mean the module is not in a directory where Drupal looks for the modules to load, which means you see it on your site, but Drupal is not looking for it where it is.

If you are using the Drupal 7 version of the module, then `fivestar_widget_form()` is not an implemented function.